# JuiceUI Tabs control doesn't work after postback

Tags: juice-ui

I have a JuiceUI Tabs control with 2 tab pages.  After a postback, clicking on the second tab doesn’t go to the tab page anymore for Chrome and Firefox.
I am using visual studio 2012, jquery 1.9.1, jquery-ui 1.10.1, and juiceui.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="font-size: 14px;">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update Tab" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <juice:Tabs ID="Tabs1" runat="server">
                <juice:TabPage ID="TabPage1" Title="First Tab" runat="server">
                    <TabContent>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <juice:Datepicker ID="Datapicker1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" />
                    </TabContent>
                </juice:TabPage>
                <juice:TabPage ID="TabPage2" Title="Second Tab" runat="server">
                    <TabContent>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label 2"></asp:Label>
                    </TabContent>
                </juice:TabPage>
            </juice:Tabs>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

This the server code:

```
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Label lbl = (Label) TabPage1.FindControl("Label1");
           if (lbl != null)
           {
               lbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
           }
       }

       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the problem with [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew), which is a fork of Juice. If you get the chance, please give it a shot and let me know if you experience the same issue.